# Mono compiler crashes when trying to compile a class that calls native code

Tags: c#, macos, mono, interop, cfrunloop

I have the following class that maps some run loop calls from native code to C# using Mono (in a mac) and the compiler just doesn't work, it crashes all the time when trying to compile it. I have removed it to a separate project containing only **this** class but it's still broken, so it seems like the issue is with this code specifically.

Has anyone seen anything like this?

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace Integration.Mac
{

    public class CommonRunLoop
    {

        static IntPtr runLoopReference;

        public static IntPtr CommonRunLoopReference {
            get {
                return runLoopReference;
            }
        }

        static CommonRunLoop() {

            AutoResetEvent lockObj = new AutoResetEvent (true);

            Thread runLoop = new Thread (delegate() {
                runLoopReference = CFRunLoopGetCurrent ();
                lockObj.Set ();
                CFRunLoopRun ();
            });

            runLoop.IsBackground = true;
            runLoop.Name = "Common-Sync-Run-Loop";
            lockObj.WaitOne();
        }

        [DllImport ("/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation")]
        extern static IntPtr CFRunLoopGetCurrent ();

        [DllImport ("/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation")]
        extern static IntPtr CFRunLoopGetMain ();

        [DllImport ("/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation")]
        extern static void CFRunLoopRun ();

    } 
}
```

The compiler output is as follows:

> Building Solution: calling-native-code-mono (Debug)
>
> Building: calling-native-code-mono (Debug) Performing main
>   compilation...
>   /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/bin/dmcs /noconfig
>   "/out:/Users/mauricio/Projects/calling-native-code-mono/bin/Debug/calling-native-code-mono.dll"
>   "/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/mono/4.0/System.dll"
>   "/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/mono/4.0/System.Core.dll"
>   /nologo /warn:4 /debug:full /optimize- /codepage:utf8 "/define:DEBUG" 
>   /t:library
>   "/Users/mauricio/Projects/calling-native-code-mono/CommonRunLoop.cs"
>   "/Users/mauricio/Projects/calling-native-code-mono/AssemblyInfo.cs"
>
> Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object   at Mono.CSharp.EmitContext.Emit
>   (OpCode opcode, Mono.CSharp.MethodSpec method) [0x00000] in :0    at Mono.CSharp.New.Emit (Mono.CSharp.EmitContext ec,
>   IMemoryLocation target) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.CSharp.VariableReference.EmitAssign (Mono.CSharp.EmitContext ec,
>   Mono.CSharp.Expression source, Boolean leave_copy, Boolean
>   prepare_for_load) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.CSharp.Assign.Emit (Mono.CSharp.EmitContext ec, Boolean
>   is_statement) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.CSharp.Assign.EmitStatement (Mono.CSharp.EmitContext ec)
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.CSharp.BlockVariableDeclaration.DoEmit (Mono.CSharp.EmitContext
>   ec) [0x00000] in :0    at Mono.CSharp.Statement.Emit
>   (Mono.CSharp.EmitContext ec) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.CSharp.Block.DoEmit (Mono.CSharp.EmitContext ec) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at Mono.CSharp.Block.Emit
>   (Mono.CSharp.EmitContext ec) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.CSharp.ExplicitBlock.Emit (Mono.CSharp.EmitContext ec) [0x00000]
>   in :0    at Mono.CSharp.ToplevelBlock.Emit
>   (Mono.CSharp.EmitContext ec) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.CSharp.Constructor.Emit () [0x00000] in :0
>   at Mono.CSharp.TypeContainer.EmitType () [0x00000] in :0    at Mono.CSharp.ModuleContainer.Emit () [0x00000] in
>   :0    at Mono.CSharp.AssemblyDefinition.Emit ()
>   [0x00000] in :0    at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Compile ()
>   [0x00000] in :0    at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Main
>   (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in :0  [ERROR]
>   FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object   at
>   Mono.CSharp.EmitContext.Emit (OpCode opcode, Mono.CSharp.MethodSpec
>   method) [0x00000] in :0    at Mono.CSharp.New.Emit
>   (Mono.CSharp.EmitContext ec, IMemoryLocation target) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at Mono.CSharp.VariableReference.EmitAssign
>   (Mono.CSharp.EmitContext ec, Mono.CSharp.Expression source, Boolean
>   leave_copy, Boolean prepare_for_load) [0x00000] in :0    at Mono.CSharp.Assign.Emit (Mono.CSharp.EmitContext ec,
>   Boolean is_statement) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.CSharp.Assign.EmitStatement (Mono.CSharp.EmitContext ec)
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.CSharp.BlockVariableDeclaration.DoEmit (Mono.CSharp.EmitContext
>   ec) [0x00000] in :0    at Mono.CSharp.Statement.Emit
>   (Mono.CSharp.EmitContext ec) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.CSharp.Block.DoEmit (Mono.CSharp.EmitContext ec) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at Mono.CSharp.Block.Emit
>   (Mono.CSharp.EmitContext ec) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.CSharp.ExplicitBlock.Emit (Mono.CSharp.EmitContext ec) [0x00000]
>   in :0    at Mono.CSharp.ToplevelBlock.Emit
>   (Mono.CSharp.EmitContext ec) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.CSharp.Constructor.Emit () [0x00000] in :0
>   at Mono.CSharp.TypeContainer.EmitType () [0x00000] in :0    at Mono.CSharp.ModuleContainer.Emit () [0x00000] in
>   :0    at Mono.CSharp.AssemblyDefinition.Emit ()
>   [0x00000] in :0    at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Compile ()
>   [0x00000] in :0    at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Main
>   (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in :0
>
> Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object   at Mono.CSharp.EmitContext.Emit
>   (OpCode opcode, Mono.CSharp.MethodSpec method) [0x00000] in :0    at Mono.CSharp.New.Emit (Mono.CSharp.EmitContext ec,
>   IMemoryLocation target) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.CSharp.VariableReference.EmitAssign (Mono.CSharp.EmitContext ec,
>   Mono.CSharp.Expression source, Boolean leave_copy, Boolean
>   prepare_for_load) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.CSharp.Assign.Emit (Mono.CSharp.EmitContext ec, Boolean
>   is_statement) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.CSharp.Assign.EmitStatement (Mono.CSharp.EmitContext ec)
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.CSharp.BlockVariableDeclaration.DoEmit (Mono.CSharp.EmitContext
>   ec) [0x00000] in :0    at Mono.CSharp.Statement.Emit
>   (Mono.CSharp.EmitContext ec) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.CSharp.Block.DoEmit (Mono.CSharp.EmitContext ec) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at Mono.CSharp.Block.Emit
>   (Mono.CSharp.EmitContext ec) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.CSharp.ExplicitBlock.Emit (Mono.CSharp.EmitContext ec) [0x00000]
>   in :0    at Mono.CSharp.ToplevelBlock.Emit
>   (Mono.CSharp.EmitContext ec) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.CSharp.Constructor.Emit () [0x00000] in :0
>   at Mono.CSharp.TypeContainer.EmitType () [0x00000] in :0    at Mono.CSharp.ModuleContainer.Emit () [0x00000] in
>   :0    at Mono.CSharp.AssemblyDefinition.Emit ()
>   [0x00000] in :0    at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Compile ()
>   [0x00000] in :0    at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Main
>   (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in :0  [ERROR]
>   FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object   at
>   Mono.CSharp.EmitContext.Emit (OpCode opcode, Mono.CSharp.MethodSpec
>   method) [0x00000] in :0    at Mono.CSharp.New.Emit
>   (Mono.CSharp.EmitContext ec, IMemoryLocation target) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at Mono.CSharp.VariableReference.EmitAssign
>   (Mono.CSharp.EmitContext ec, Mono.CSharp.Expression source, Boolean
>   leave_copy, Boolean prepare_for_load) [0x00000] in :0    at Mono.CSharp.Assign.Emit (Mono.CSharp.EmitContext ec,
>   Boolean is_statement) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.CSharp.Assign.EmitStatement (Mono.CSharp.EmitContext ec)
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.CSharp.BlockVariableDeclaration.DoEmit (Mono.CSharp.EmitContext
>   ec) [0x00000] in :0    at Mono.CSharp.Statement.Emit
>   (Mono.CSharp.EmitContext ec) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.CSharp.Block.DoEmit (Mono.CSharp.EmitContext ec) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at Mono.CSharp.Block.Emit
>   (Mono.CSharp.EmitContext ec) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.CSharp.ExplicitBlock.Emit (Mono.CSharp.EmitContext ec) [0x00000]
>   in :0    at Mono.CSharp.ToplevelBlock.Emit
>   (Mono.CSharp.EmitContext ec) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.CSharp.Constructor.Emit () [0x00000] in :0
>   at Mono.CSharp.TypeContainer.EmitType () [0x00000] in :0    at Mono.CSharp.ModuleContainer.Emit () [0x00000] in
>   :0    at Mono.CSharp.AssemblyDefinition.Emit ()
>   [0x00000] in :0    at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Compile ()
>   [0x00000] in :0    at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Main
>   (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in :0  Build
>   complete -- 1 error, 0 warnings
>
> ---------------------- Done ----------------------
>
> Build: 1 error, 0 warnings

Comment: Could you please file this on Mono bug tracker? That shouldn't happen. https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/index.cgi

Comment: It's already in there - https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=6529

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

At the beginning of the file fixed it, `DLLImport` is at that namespace. Not sure why the compiler didn't just complain about it instead of crashing.

A bug report was filled [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=6529).